# Python: Branch of options in efficient and infinite way

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, branch

I am creating a game in python and im trying to find a way to have a story and the user chooses which path to go on, now this sounds easy, but once you add too many if's inside of if's then things get messy.
i am trying to find the most clear, efficient and infinite way ( you can continually add branches to the story lines w/out the computer crashing or something.

I am using repl.it and python 2.7.13

and seriously, how many times do you have to read this to figure out it is a path branching game where you choose a path that branches onto other paths, not a room N E S W game!

Comment: To avoid excessive nesting you can make each if statement call a function.

Comment: Do you need to use repl.it? Can't you install Python on your computer? BTW, you should be learning Python 3.

Comment: no Im using it so i don't need to be at home to work

Comment: and no I like python 2 and also py3 is totally different, its not even the same language.

Comment: I also like Python 2, and if you don't need Unicode then string processing in Python 2 can be faster than in Python 3. However, Python 2 will not be supported after 2020, so it's probably not a great strategy at this stage to get locked into Python 2.

Comment: is there a website that teaches how to move from python2 to 3

Comment: The official Python 3 tutorial is a good place to start, and there are some good tutorials listed in the SO Python wiki page: [What tutorial should I read?](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F). But I guess it would be good to have a succinct document aimed at competent Python 2 coders who want to get up to speed on Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

I figured out how to answer my own question, here's my code:

area1 = 'SrtR'

```
def dict_area1():
    global area1
    if area1 == "SrtR":
        print ("you wake up in a forest")
        print ('''what do you do?
Choices:
    1 = find shelter
    2 = build shelter
    3 = go back 2 sleep''')
        while True:
            AC1 = input('>')
            if AC1 == '1':
                area1 = "area_1_SmlShed"
            elif AC1 == '2':
                area1 = "area_2_PileLog"
            elif AC1 == '3':
                print ('you wake up an hour later, in the same place, it is now afternoon')
                continue
            else:
                print ('that is not a choice')
                continue
            dict_area1()
    if area1 == 'area_1_SmlShed':
        print ('after searching for about an hour, you come across a small shed')
        print ('the shed seems to be abandoned')
        print ('''
Choices:
    1 = go into shed
    2 = scout shed
    3 = keep looking''')
        while True:
            AC1 = input('>')
            if AC1 == '1':
                area1 = "area_1_InShed"
            elif AC1 == '2':
                area1 = "area_BackShed"
            elif AC1 == '3':
                print ('After looking for another hour, you can\'t seem to find anything else')
            else:
                print ('that is not a choice')
                continue
dict_area1()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach may depend on your level of knowledge of Python.  I think David Whitlock's suggestion of using a dictionary is a good start.  If you want a more advanced approach you would define your own Python objects (classes) and then build your 'world' out of them (e.g. rooms, objects, players, capabilities, etc.).  This would be infinitely extensible.

I did some looking round and found this ready-made module for doing exactly that: [Create your own Classic Text Adventure with Python](http://blog.trinket.io/python-text-adventure/).  Check out how it works.

Comment: There's a more up-to-date version of the code here: https://github.com/gever/bwx-adventure

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a dictionary for all the options. [Here is an example](https://github.com/riverrun/cheesemaker/blob/master/cheesemaker/gui.py#L146) - the `self.orient_dict` is then called on line 220.

Comment: I don't know how that would work since I am making a storyline based game

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the right data structure for your adventure. For a text adventure with "rooms", a graph would be very appropriate. Basically you will create a `room` class which are nodes in the graph. Each room has references to the rooms that you can travel to from there. A very simple `room` class will have `north`, `south`, `east` and `west` members to be able to travel in each direction. A more complex game can have a `dict` of rooms where the keys describe the direction to travel to get to the next room.